# Accessing router behind modem/router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I have a router which is located upstairs connected to the modem downstairs through a powerline adapter. I am able to access the modem which is located downstairs through the router but connecting to the router from the modem does not work. Is there a way to connect to the router behind the modem and also see the devices that are connected to the router?

Network Diagram

```
                    |-------------------------------------> Router (located upstairs)
                    |                                          |
Internet ----> Modem/Router (located downstairs)               |---> computer and NAS
                    |
                    |---> computers, wireless devices and printer
```

Thanks

Comment: do you want to connect the router or the computer / nas behind the router? If you want to connect the router what you want to get? The web frontend? SSH access? And, what router is it?

Comment: My main router is the one that is located downstairs and the one that is located upstairs is the second router which extends the wifi range. Both of them are connected to each other. My computer and has are connected to the upstairs router but if I connect to my main one which is located downstairs it would not be able to see the devices on the network plus I cannot connect to the router (upstairs) from the router (downstairs) but it works the opposite way. The only way I could access the router from the main router was to enable remote management in the settings.

Answer (score 2):

You want the upstairs router to actually act as just a bridge/switch, not really a router/gateway.

On the upstairs router, disable NAT and DHCP service so that it just bridges between WAN and LAN. If it doesn't have an option for this, then take the Ethernet cable that's in its WAN port (i.e. the cable that goes downstairs) and move it to one of its LAN ports (all of the LAN ports are on the same bridge/switch). If it doesn't have an option to disable its DHCP server, set its DHCP address pool size to zero.